# Как внести изменения в скрипт модального окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, всплывающее-окно

Я всех приветствую! Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать скрипт модального окна. Это окно является справкой для пользователя. Мне нужно, чтобы по умолчанию окно было уже в открытом состоянии, а кнопка открытия была недоступна. При закрытии окна нужен один из двух эффектов (какой возможно сделать):
1) окно закрывается, после чего сразу в этом же месте появляется кнопка открытия, и тут же она перемещается видимым образом в правый верхний угол экрана.
2) окно закрывается, после чего появляется кнопка открытия уже сразу в правом верхнем углу экрана, с анимацией (анимация в виде колокольчика что ли, для привлечения внимания пользователя.)
Очень прошу помощи! Благодарю!

**html:**

```
<button class="click">Открыть</button>
<div class="message">Сообщение
  <button class="okay">Закрыть</button>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.click {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #260016;
}
.message {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 140px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
  color: button;
  padding: 60px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.message.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.okay {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e68a6c;
}
```

**js:**

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    // открываем окно
    $('button').click(function(evt){
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $('.message').addClass('active');
    });
    // закрываем окно
    $('.message').click(function(evt){
      evt.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).add('.okay').click(function() {
      $('.message').removeClass('active');
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доработай так(этот скрипт надо вставить в дополнение к существующему у тебя):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).hide().css('opacity', '0')
    });
    $('button').click();

    $('.okay').click(function() {
        $('.click').show()
            .css('transition', 'all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 0s')
            .css('opacity', '1')
            .css('position', 'fixed')
            .css('left', '0px')
            .css('height', 'opx');
    });

});
```

Суть в общем ясна должна быть.